# Nodejs can't be found after installing in ubuntu

Tags: node.js

I'm following [this](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall) guide to installing nodejs as part of [prerequisite](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) for react-native.

I've entered the following commands;

```
# Using Ubuntu
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_15.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Everything is shown to be installed correctly. However, whenever i type `nodejs --version` it tells me that it doesn't exist and that i could install it using sudo apt...

Comment: Did you mean: `node --version`?  (The command is `node` not `nodejs`)

Comment: Oh, thanks. The tutorial said i should do 'nodejs --version' ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running nodejs uses the command `node`. So in your case you should try `node --version`